About composing accessible functors
In Efimov's recent preprint K-theory and localizing invariants of large categories
he uses, in section 2, the fact that composing accessible functors between presentable stable categories agrees with the composition of correspondence. That is, given an accessible functor
$$A \to C$$
one can form a short exact sequence in $\mathrm{Pr}_\text{St}^{LL}$
$$A \to B \to C$$ as described in his paper in proposition 1.2.
Further, given two correspondence—one from $A$ to $C$ and one from $C$ to $E$—one can form a correspondence from $A$ to $E$ by taking the subcategory generated by $A$ and $E$ inside $B \amalg_C D$ where $D$ is an extension of $E$ by $C$.
I tried briefly to see why the two ways of composing are the same but I failed. Could someone spell out the details here for me?

Following an email from Efimov, I can now complete this direct check.
First let's give the maps names. The first SES is
$$A \xrightarrow{f_1} B \xrightarrow{f_2} C$$
while the second is
$$C \xrightarrow{f_3} D \xrightarrow{f_4} E.$$
The first SES corresponds to the accessible functor $f_2^{RR}f_1$ and the second to $f_4^{RR}f_3$ (where as in the question $R$ superscript means taking right adjoint).
The composition of these two correspondences is the subcategory in
$B \amalg_{C} D$ generated by $A$ and $D$.
To find the accessible functor this composed correspondence corresponds to, we just need to compute
$$\operatorname{Hom}(i_Df_4^Re,i_Bf_1a)$$
for $e \in E$ and $a \in A$ where $i_B$, $i_D$ are the inclusion functors into the pushout category.
So the goal is to compute the composition $f_4^{RR}i_D^Ri_Bf_1$.
Now, we know that $B \coprod_C D \cong B \times_C D$ with the right adjoint functors (so $f_2^{RR}$ and $f_3^R$).
We can compute that
$$i_B : B \to B \coprod_C D \cong B \times_C D$$
is defined by
$b \mapsto (b,f_3f_2^{RR}b,-)$ where $-$ stands for the natural homotopy between $f_2^{RR}b$ and $f_3^Rf_3f_2^{RR}b$.
We also know that
$$i_D^R : B \times_C D \to D$$ is simply the second projection. Hence, the functor we need to compute is $f_4^{RR}f_3f_2^{RR}f_1$ as desired.
Note (as an aside) that $i_D^L$ the left adjoint is induced by $f_2 \amalg id$.
Addendum:
The diagram in $\mathrm{Pr}^{LL}_\text{St}$
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A @>{f_1}>> B @>{f_2}>> C \\
@V{\cong}VV @V{i_B}VV @VV{f_3}V \\
A @>>> B \amalg_C D @>{i_D^R}>> D \\
\end{CD}
has enough data in $\mathrm{Pr}^L_\text{St}$ to make the pushout an absolute $\mathrm{Stab}$-enriched colimit. (Just like short exact sequence in $\mathrm{Pr}^{LL}_\text{St}$ which is a split-exact sequence in $\mathrm{Pr}^L_\text{St}$.)
Hence it is also a pushout in presentable categories with accessible functors. This is enough to pushout the  $f_2^R \vdash f_2^{RR}$ adjunction along $f_3$ to conclude that
\begin{CD}
B @>{f_2^{RR}}>> C \\
@V{i_B}VV @VV{f_3}V \\
B \amalg_C D @>{i_D^{RR}}>> D \\
\end{CD}
from where we can finish as above.
